# Kernel Command Line Interface - kcli: What is it and why do I need it?

Tags: linux, command-line, kernel, linux-kernel

I saw several times a command line interface called kcli on embedded systems. After googling around I found a LWN article introducing the first patch shipping it: [LWN - kcli](https://lwn.net/Articles/231582/)

But the article is not very detailed and the included link to the repository does not work anymore.

Has somebody more details about what the kcli is? What is it capable of and why do I need it present on a Linux system? Which commands are supported?

Comment: it appears to be a shell that runs in kernel space ... you definitely do not need it on a Linux system that runs programs in user space

Comment: But what can I do with the kcli? What is its purpose?

Comment: the description implies that there are no user space programs ... everything runs in kernel space ... this is meant for RTOS type of a system ... you still need a terminal window of some kind

Answer (score 0):

It is not included in the linux kernel.

lklm message : [Hans Peter Anvin](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/4/23/297)

> We already have that, it's called initramfs; you can use either busybox 
>   or klibc ash in this space, and no need to run it in kernel space.
>
> Running this kind of crap in kernel space is lunacy in the extreme.